# Installing activeX control as a standard user

Tags: vb6, activex, hta, activexobject

I have an activeX control made in VB6 that is packed in a cabinet along with an inf file, and I'm having trouble installing it as non-admin (to avoid the UAC prompt).
Contents of the inf file:

```
[version]
signature="$CHICAGO$"
AdvancedINF=2.0

[Add.Code]
fppd.ocx=fppd.ocx

[Deployment]
InstallScope=user

[fppd.ocx]
file-win32-x86=thiscab
clsid={B175C045-20AE-4660-98CE-544AB2143E19}
FileVersion=1.0.0.0
RedirectToHKCU=yes
```

HTML code that calls the control:

```
<object id="mini" width=640 height=480 classid="CLSID:B175C045-20AE-4660-98CE-544AB2143E19" codebase="fppd.cab" </object>
```

Nothing happens when the page opens. The space reserved for the control disappears shortly after the page is loaded. The control is not installed or launched at all.
If I remove the [Deployment] part from the inf, or change InstallScope from user to machine, it works normally but requires admin rights which is not what I want.

Do I need to change the code of the control to install as user? Maybe it doesn't know how to install itself as user. Or maybe I'm missing something in the inf or cab file?

Comment: Maybe see http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-US/887a9397-4d40-4171-9ff6-05730b503ea0/nonadmin-activexinstall-ie8-winxp-vs-win7

Comment: My guess: because RegisterServer=yes is missing under [fppd.ocx] ?

Comment: With RegisterServer=yes it wouldn't install even as admin so I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Per machine is installed to `HKLM\software\classes`. You can write the info that would appear there to `HKCU\Software\Classes` which is the per user install key..